# Google docs, how to paste link keeping normal look

Tags: unicode, google-docs

Here is the link I am trying to paste to google docs

```
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Си_(язык_программирования)
```

But when I copy and paste I get

```
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
```

I always have to write links with my hands because of this effect. This is very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-ASCII characters aren't allowed in URLs, so the version with percent-escaped characters is the "normal" URL. Modern browsers assume that URLs are UTF-8 encoded and decode them before displaying them in the address bar, but if it contains non-ASCII characters, *it's not a URL*. When you copy a URL from the address bar, the actual percent-encoded URL is copied because that's the only form that is guaranteed to work with every other application.

If you're sure that the application you're pasting the URL into supports pseudo-URLs with Unicode characters, it helps to copy not the full URL but only a part of it. For example, if you select only the "Си_(язык_программирования)" part, it will be copied as Unicode text (at least in Firefox and Chrome).